# Building a recursive function in Python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, recursion

For an intro comp sci lab I'm trying to build a recursive function that counts the number of occurrences of a given letter in a string without using built in methods or loops. I'm pretty stumped without the use of myStr.count. Can anyone offer a tip? should I try something that checks the identity of myStr[0] and returns 0 if letter != myStr[0]?

```
def count(letter, myStr, theLen):

#Code for def count 

def main():

    print ("The count of letter a is: ", count("a", "abacdadaad", 10))
    print ("The count of letter b is: ", count("b", "abacdadaad", 10))
    print ("The count of letter c is: ", count("c", "abacdadaad", 10))
    print ("The count of letter d is: ", count("d", "abacdadaad", 10))

main()
```

Comment: Please ident your code properly, with python it's a pretty big deal :)

Comment: *should I try something that checks the identity of myStr[0] and returns 0 if letter != myStr[0]* -- You are definitely on the right track. Also think what happens when letter == myStr[0], then implement recursively.

Comment: Also, please use proper PEP8 style. I.e. no camelCase (also, `myStr` and `theLen` are awful names no matter which style) and no space between function name and opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when writing something recursively, the main problem is to determine what is the condition for return. Obviously, when counting letters in a string, it is the moment when you are testing the last character of the string.

You could try:

```
def recursive(string, letter):

    if len(string) == 1 and string == letter:
        return 1;

    elif len(string) == 1:
        return 0;

    if string[0] == letter:
        count = 1 + recursive(string[1:], letter)

    else:
        count = recursive(string[1:], letter)

    return count
```